# What is the alternative for utils in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have this piece of code that repeats in 3 places

```
      if (orientation == AppConstants.LANDSCAPE) {
        width = 
        height = 
      }else{
        width = 
        height = 
      }
      imageUrl.let {
        val options = RequestOptions()
            .centerCrop()
            .override(width, height)
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
            .apply(options)
            .into(cardView.mainImageView)
      }
```

I don't know which is the best solution to have in one place the code of calculating width and height based on orientation ?
I don't think I can replace it with extension function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the calculation part but if you want to create a utility class, you can create `MyUtils.kt` as follows:

```
object MyUtils {

    fun myFunction(imageUrl: String) {
        // Your code above...
    }

    ...
}
```

You can call it later like this:

```
MyUtils.myFunction(imageUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a funtion like this:

```
fun getWidthHeight() = if (orientation == AppConstants.LANDSCAPE) {
    Pair(45, 86)
} else {
    Pair(78, 35)
}
```

And you can call this function like this:

```
val (width, height) = getWidthHeight()
```

Answer (score -1):

Create simple class and call method by getting instance of class.no need to make it static to avoid unnecessary increasing app memory burden.